# Does "equivalence" of sets of axioms imply equality of the resulting theories?

Tags: logic, meta-math

For a set of sentences $A$, denote by $\langle A\rangle$ the set of sentences which can be derived from $A$ in some formal system.

Define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on the set of finite sets of sentences as follows:

$S_1\sim S_2$ if and only if

1. for every sentence $s\in S_1$, $S_2\vdash s$ - i.e. $S_2\vdash S_1$
2. for every sentence $s\in S_2$, $S_1\vdash s$ - i.e. $S_1\vdash S_2$

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be consistent sets of sentences.

Is it the case that $A_1\sim A_2\implies \langle A_1\rangle=\langle A_2\rangle$

---

A quick proof sketch suggests that the answer is "yes," but I'd like to verify this against a more formal proof.

proof-sketch:

$A$ is an axiomatization of a theory $T$, and we write $T=\langle A\rangle$ iff $A\vdash t$ for every $t\in T$ ($A\vdash T$ for short) (def)

If $A_1\sim A_2$, then $A_1\vdash A_2$ (def)

Suppose $A_2\vdash T$. Then $\langle A_2\rangle$.

Suppose $A_1\sim A_2$. Then $A_1\vdash A_2$.

From $A_1\vdash A_2$ and $A_2\vdash T$, derive $A_1\vdash T$ (something vaguely cut elimination - this is where I'm unsure).

Either way, I imagine that this is a proven theorem somewhere, so any reference is appreciated!

Comment: This result is correct from meta-maths point of view, the theoreis themselves cannot prove that(because "for every t∈T" is not something they can talk about), I don't think it has a name, also ⟨A⟩ is usually denoted as Th(A).

Comment: @ℋolo The theories in question may well be able to do that - take e.g. $\mathsf{ZFC}$, or (first-order) $\mathsf{PA}$, or really anything to which Godel's theorem applies. And the argument itself also goes through in any reasonable background theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

*(I preseume $\langle X\rangle=\{p:X\vdash p\}$. This is generally denoted "$Ded(X)$" or "$Th(X)$.")*

However, I can't really follow your proof sketch, so let me summarize the situation below (this may be what you intended):

---

The key point is that **proofs are finite**: if $A\vdash p$ then $A'\vdash p$ for some finite $A'\subseteq A$, since every proof can only use finitely many axioms. So infinite sets of axioms don't pose any difficulty here.

We can use this as follows. Suppose $X$ proves each sentence in $Y$ and $Y$ proves $p$. Then some finite $\{y_1,...,y_k\}\subseteq Y$ proves $p$. We now "paste together" the relevant $X$-proofs of $y_1,...,y_k$ to get an $X$-proof $\pi_1$ of $y_1\wedge ...\wedge y_k$; conversely, we can turn the $\{y_1,...,y_k\}$-proof of $p$ into a $\{y_1\wedge ...\wedge y_k\}$-proof $\pi_2$ of $p$. We now "compose" the proofs $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ to get an $X$-proof of $p$, as desired.

*(Incidentally, this "composability" property is generally considered fundamental in the study of abstract logics; for example, the lovely volume ["Algebraizable logics"](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-77-396/8) by Blok/Pigozzi lists it as axiom $(3)$ for deductive systems.)*

It's worth noting that the "semantic" version is substantially more interesting: there, we need the highly nontrivial [**compactness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) (or the equally-nontrivial [**completeness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem), which will let us reduce it to the straightforward "syntactic" version above).

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know when the converse holds (i.e. if $Th(A_1)=Th(A_2)$ then $A_1\sim A_2$ for finite $A_1$ and $A_2$)?

Comment: @R.Burton Sorry, I just saw this. Yes, the converse also holds - in fact it holds more simply: since $A_1\subseteq Th(A_1)$ and $A_2\subseteq Th(A_2)$, from $Th(A_1)\supseteq Th(A_2)$ we get for each $a\in A_2$ that $A_1\vdash a$, and similarly in the other direction. (And again $A_1$ and $A_2$ need not be finite.)